# Change the position of a frame in Tkinter, Involving Classes and functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to move a frame on my GUI, but I am unable to do so because of my classes. How can I move the frame2 with a

```
Slider1.SetVal(x=20, y=30)
```

while keeping my classes.

My Code

```
class Slider:
def __init__ (self,Name, x, y, Height, Width, KnobHeight, KnobWidth, LowVal, HighVal, BgColor, FgColor):
    self.Name = Name
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.Height = Height
    self.Width = Width
    self.KnobHeight = KnobHeight
    self.KnobWidth = KnobWidth
    self.LowVal = LowVal
    self.HighVal = HighVal
    self.BgColor = BgColor
    self.FgColor = FgColor

def Display(self):
    frame = Frame(self.Name, width=self.Width, height=self.Height, colormap="new", bg=self.BgColor)
    frame.place(x=self.x, y=self.y)

    frame2 = Frame(self.Name, width=self.KnobWidth, height=self.KnobHeight, colormap="new", bg=self.FgColor)
    frame2.place(x=(self.x + self.Width/2 - self.KnobWidth/2), y=(self.Height - self.KnobHeight/2 + self.y))
   
def SetVal(self):
    Main.update()
    frame2.place(x=33, y=5)

window1 = Window(Main)
Slider1 = Slider(Main,100,60,200,15,15,35,0,80,"White","Green")
Slider1.Display()
Slider1.SetVal(3,30)
Main.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to change `frame2` to `self.frame2`, otherwise it is just a local variable inside `Display()` and cannot be accessed inside `SetVal()`.

Comment: That works, Thanks